# php - How to efficient writing mysql update in this situation?

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

I want to let my database article reclassified. I have no good idea to Classification articles more better. I build a reference table, put every probably words of each category in it. 
then I query from the main table `articles`, explore every article contents into words and put them into reference table to match whether the article is belong which category? then do a update. 
I want control every category has a max articles are 5. I write some code like this.

```
<?php
header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die("can not connect Mysql Server");
mysql_select_db("mydb",$db);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT content,id,directory,date FROM articles WHERE Order By date DESC");//get all the articles from database
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$id = $row['id'];
$content = $row['content'];
$words = preg_split("/\s+/",$content); 
$uniqueWords = array_keys(array_flip($words)); 
$parts = '';
foreach($uniqueWords as $word){     
$parts[] = " tag1 = '$word' OR tag2 = '$word' OR tag3 = '$word' OR tag4 = '$word' OR tag5 = '$word' ";   
$where = implode(" OR ", $parts);
mysql_select_db("mydb",$db);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags1 WHERE ($where) AND category='art' "); // put every word from each article into `tag1` database whether the article is match category='art'
$citn = '';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $citn = $row['category'];
        } 
    $catnew = $citn;
mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET directory = '".$catnew."' WHERE id = '".$id."' AND directory ='0'  Order By date DESC LIMIT 5"); // update first 5 articles which is match category='art' 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags1 WHERE ($where) AND category='fashion' "); // put every word from each article into `tag1` database whether the article is match category='fashion'
$citn = '';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $citn .= $row['category']."|" ;
        } 
    $catnew = explode("|",$citn);
mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET directory = '".$catnew."' WHERE id = '".$id."' AND directory ='0'  Order By date DESC LIMIT 5"); // update first 5 articles which is match category='fashion'
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags1 WHERE ($where) AND category='travel' ");// put every word from each article into `tag1` database whether the article is match category='travel'
... // there have 20 `category`, each is the same judge method.
}
}
mysql_close($db);
?>
```

but the speed is very very slow, I test 60 articles in my articles db table, 20 category in tag1 table. But during the update it will echo  `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in...`

How to make an efficient update Or is there has better way to do this work? Thanks.

this is my articles table

```
id | title | link | content | date | directory
1  | ...   | ...  | ...     | ...  |  0 // all directory value are `0` 
2  | ...   | ...  | ...     | ...  |  0 
3  | ...   | ...  | ...     | ...  |  0
... // more 60 articles
```

this is my tag1 table

```
category | tag1    | tag2   | tag3       | tag4    |  tag5   
tourism  | tourism | travel | tour       | journey |  trip
fashion  | style   | vogue  | fashion    | mode    |  Popular
art      | paint   |
... // more 20 categories
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive me, I feel I must have read your code wrong as, as I read it theres a number of questions about your code that puzzle me.

Firstly you have a number of areas such as:

```
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$citn = $row['category'];
}
```

which, will when run of course only show the last entry in $citn, but in your where clause you specify the category must be 'art' for example, as a result, whats the point of the query, you already knew the answer to be 'art' ? Unless this is simplified code.

So, Im left wondering what you think your code does, as far as I can tell, the first one for 'art' will return $citn as 'art' the second will return "fashion|fashion.." for each line in the tags1 table that it finds, the last update will probably fail if theres more than 1 fashion, as exploding it into an array Im not sure how the SQL will handle a PHP array dumped in there. The last query you dont show any code for, so.. Im a little lost.

I get the impression you wanted to explode the text of a given article, and then see if 5 or more tags it has appear in the cateogry. If so, I dont see this code doing that.

As I said, I may have misread it somehow.

Comment: `I get the impression you wanted to explode the text of a given article, and then see if 5 or more tags it has appear in the cateogry. If so, I dont see this code doing that.`, How to write a write code if my mistake cause a `Fatal error`?  thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you need this code to do? It isnt as clear to me at least, from your code as I think you think it is.

Comment: I want explode the text of a given article, and then see if there is one word of the article match 1 tag which it has appear in the cateogry, then upsate this article in this cateogry name. For example. If a article like `have a nice journey` , the article contain a word `journey` match category `tourism`, so update the article `directory` as a value `tourism`. Then there allow max 5 articles which `directory` = `tourism`. Thanks.

Comment: I have checked out the fault by myself, I put a `}` in a wrong position.  Thank u.

Comment: Ah, that makes a little more sense.